# cakephp2.X validation on edit view

Tags: php, html, cakephp, file-upload

When i create a project, the image upload validation working fine but when i'm editing the project, it always asking me to upload file again. Using firebug i checked img_upload input it has value "Lighthouse.jpg".

How can i overcome this?

Below My model validation

```
     'img_upload' = array(
         'extension' => array(
           'rule' => array('extension', array('png','jpg','jpeg')),
           'message' => "Only png,jpg,jpeg Files Allowed",
         )
      );
```

Below My html code :

```
echo $this->Form->create('Project',array('type'=>'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('img_upload'); 
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

Comment: This validation rule would work with file type inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Your current rule is making the file upload a required field, so will error if a file is not uploaded on edit. Try adding `'allowEmpty' => true` to your validation rule to prevent it from being required:-

```
 'img_upload' = array(
     'extension' => array(
         'rule' => array('extension', array('png','jpg','jpeg')),
         'message' => "Only png,jpg,jpeg Files Allowed",
         'allowEmpty' => true,
     ) 
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try changing your input code from

```
echo $this->Form->input('img_upload');
```

to this

```
echo $this->Form->input('img_upload','type'=>'file');
```